# Should I use OLE Clipboard mechanism or standard Clipboard API?

Tags: windows, ole, paste

I'm adding copy and paste functionality to an existing Windows application. [This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35awt0bz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) suggests using the OLE Clipboard mechanism rather than the standard clipboard API. Wondered what the concensus is on this? I thought the OLE stuff had died a bit of a death and I didn't want to acquaint myself with all the classes unless there was some benefit.

Comment: huh!?! Thought MS killed off OLE.... odd.... unless the page is misleading - it references VS2005 which is uhhh what 6 years ago, I would thought the standard clipboard API is the guaranteed way to do clipboard functionality....

Comment: @tommieb75 No way MS killed of OLE, they just renamed it to COM. And all OLE/COM stuff works just fine, it's very complicated though I'd stay away from it.

Comment: @Johan: No, it wasn't "renamed to COM". It's actually the other way around. OLE is a particular set of COM interfaces used to consume and interact with OLE objects. Nor is it dead: the standard clipboard doesn't give you any way of sharing OLE objects between applications.

Comment: @tommieb75: No, they didn't kill off OLE. The page isn't out-of-date, the one for VS 2010 says exactly the same thing (check the "Other Versions" drop-down). The difference is that the standard clipboard provides no functionality to link in a bitmap or a text document that stays synced with the original. That's what OLE offers to you. For standard copy-and-paste functionality, you don't need OLE.

Comment: well... I suffered a brain fart there... honest :P OLE to COM ... and anyway I used the wrong expression, as Johan said - "renamed" ftw... :) hey... am human too right? :D

Comment: Sorry Gray but: "The first implementation of COM shipped in a release form as part of OLE 2.0 1993" --Don Box Essential COM   "in 1994 Microsoft stated that OLE 2 would just be known as "OLE", and that OLE was no longer an acronym, but a name for **all** of the company's component technologies." In 1996 Microsoft renamed all OLE technologies to ActiveX, except for the parts related to Microsoft Office which were named DCOM. I can go on.

Comment: @CodyGray, VS 2015 docs says the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you need the facilities provided by OLE, I would just stick to good old-fashioned clipboard. It's much easier to use.